# php - how to shorten a string outputed?

Tags: php

im using php

if i have an uknown length of a string being outputted how can i limit it to only 16 characters to be outputted?

Answer (score 8):

the function is called substr.

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

so:

```
return substr($mystring,0,16);
```

should do it.

Answer (score 4):

The above methods, mentioning `substr` would help you. But, in case if your string contains multibyte characters (non-english characters), `mb_substr` should be used, which is a safe multi-byte substring function.

Answer (score 3):

I personally like this one if it is a blog or something:

```
<?php

if(strlen($string) > 16) { 
echo substr($string,0,16) . "...";
}else{
echo $string;
}

?>
```

This way it won't truncate the string if its below 16 characters. Otherwise, it will add an ellipsis.

Comment: Should the elipses be considered part of the 16 characters?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the code that you're using now?  I'm going to go off the basis that you have a function returning a string of an unknown length.  All you have to do is use the substr function.

```
$shorterString = substr( some_function(), 0, 16 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substr($input_string, 0, 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr](http://php.net/substr) function like this.

```
$text = "I am pretty long text.";
echo $text;                        //outputs I am pretty long text.
echo substr($text, 0, 16);         //outputs I am pretty long
```

Answer (score 0):

use [substr](http://php.net/substr)

```
 echo substr( $str,0, 16 )
```

Answer (score 0):

> $str = "More than 16 characters of
>   text in this string.";
>
> print substr( $str,0, 16 );